# Change region in an app between AWS-China and AWS-Global

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, great-firewall-of-china

AWS noob here.

Apparently cross region replication is impossible with AWS-china.

I'm thinking about an android app that could change the AWS region they're using based on their location.

For example:
If i'm in USA my app would be connected to global-aws. When I travel to China my app gives me a dialog to connect to the aws-china.
Since data replication is impossible the app would recommend the me to create my account(duplicate the account if possible) on the Chinese server and use the app within China.
Once outside of China app returns to global-aws and works normally.

Is this scenario possible with a single app that can work seamlessly cross region?

Or am I better off start working on my Chinese specific version of the app? If so how do I deal when a global-aws user visits China and wants to connect with Chinese users?

Comment: cross region replication of what?  S3?  Dynamo?

Comment: How will you keep the data in sync between the 2 regions?

Comment: @helloV in our case we don't really need to sync all aws-global data on aws-china side. Only users who move between regions can have accounts on either side. Simply put, much like realms in World of Warcraft.

Comment: @DanFarrell EC, S3. did I write my question clear enough so anybody could get the idea? if not please let me know what to clarify.

Comment: *"Apparently cross region replication is impossible with AWS-china."*  True in some cases, but not necessarily relevant.  For example, I have an application in the US, France, and Spain that does not rely on any replication services provided by AWS.  What is a *specific* problem you believe AWS-provided replication across the service partition would have solved?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Major problem with China is very slow internet connection to regions outside China. Single web request waits at least 5 seconds to get a response.
After all even replication couldn't have solved it perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data into/out of China is a complex topic, as are VPNs and direct connects, plus licensing for all this.

From your description seems you just want GEO-DNS so in China you connect to a Chinese AWS server, which is easy enough, if you have the server/license.

Steve Mushero, CEO
ChinaNetCloud

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. That just might be exactly what i'm looking for.